# Publishing COM/ActiveX interface using SOAP - what's the best solution?

Tags: windows, com, soap, activex, soa

We have a COM api (Windows DLL file) that other systems want to access using SOAP. What would be the best choice for SOAP-enabling this?

Interesting parameters are:

- License costs
- Ease of setup and maintenance
- Ease of configuration/development if needed
- Compatibility
- Security, security updates etc.

All suggestions are welcome, please provide some facts about why you think the solution is good.

Comment: Some other solutions I thought about, are:
* Find a product that automatically generates SOAP program code from a COM interface specification
* Find a SOAP/COM gateway product
* Use Apache & PHP

I am open to all ideas, suggestions and information about experience with one of the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd come with .NET and WCF. It is easy to develop thin .NET wrapper for COM objects and WCF gives you SOAP. You can choose between IIS or self-hosting.

- License cost: you need Visual Studio and Windows Server licenses (for IIS hosting option). .NET and WCF runtimes are free.
- Ease of setup and maintenance: not sure what should be here
- Ease of configuration/development: WCF is very easy to use in development
- Compatibility: WCF adheres to SOAP and WS-* extensions
- Security: IIS 7 is secure platform

Exposing COM Components to the .NET Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3%28VS.71%29.aspx

About WCF: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

WCF in more details (using SOAP): msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

PS: Sorry, it doesn't allow me to post several hyperlinks